# Access mounted volumes via the command line

Tags: command-line, mount, external-hdd

I've plugged an external hdd into my usb port, and it shows up on the desktop and in nautilus. How can i access this mounted hdd via the command line?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

automounted drives usually sit on /media/{label of your partition}. You can browse into it  by cd command in terminal
say if my pendrive is labeled SAGAR

```
cd /media/SAGAR
```

You can view the path in nautilus with ctrl+l and cd from terminal copying the path as well

EDIT: In Newer version, the username is used for directory: /media/${USER}/{SOME_HASH}

Answer (score 1):

Every mounted devices have a "mount point" where they are mounted to. You can try to guess them (most removable stuffs are mounted into directories inside `/media`), but a nicer way to use the `mount` command within a shell, so you can see the mounted file systems. Then it's easy to check the directories you need to look ("something on somewhere" at every lines, look at "somewhere"). Also you can install a nautilus extension, in packages nautilus-terminal and nautilus-open-terminal, as far as I remember, one of these can open a terminal for you at the location where you are in nautilus, so you don't even need to use a single `cd` command to get there :) But anyway, if you're using nautilus you can navigate to the device's directory you are interested in, and the location bar will show you (or you may need to press CTRL-L then ...)

Comment: command is "mount" not mound ...

Comment: well of course, it was only a typo! Thanks for noticing!

Answer (score 0):

It may be useful to do a 'disk free' check `df -h` - this should show where the main partition is mounted. The device will probably appear as `dev/sda`, `dev/sda` `dev/sdb` or similar e.g.

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
...
/dev/sdb1       100G  0G   100   0%   /media/...
```